# Placing ticks on specific values

Tags: python, matplotlib

Say I have a plot like the one below and I want to place **Y ticks** (and tick values) on specific locations. For example,   only on the highest value (`1.0`) and lowest value (`-1`).

How can I do that?

```
t = np.arange(0.0, 100.0, 0.1)
s = np.sin(0.1*np.pi*t)*np.exp(-t*0.01)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(t,s)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To only place ticks on the minimum and maximum value you can use:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(0.0, 100.0, 0.1)
s = np.sin(0.1*np.pi*t)*np.exp(-t*0.01)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(t,s)

ylims = ax.get_ylim()
ax.set_yticks(ylims)

xlims = ax.get_xlim()
ax.set_xticks(xlims)

plt.show()
```

[`ax.get_ylim()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_ylim) returns a tuple with the minimum and maximum values. You can then use [`ax.set_yticks()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks) to choose the y-ticks (in this case I have simply used the min and max y-values).

#### EDIT

You mentioned the use of [`Locator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#tick-locating) and [`Formatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#tick-formatting) objects in your comment. I've included another example below which makes use of these to:

1. Set the major tick positions;
2. Set the minor tick positions (they are small but they are there);
3. Format the major tick strings.

The code is commented and so should be understandable, if you need any more help then let me know.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator, LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter

t = np.arange(0.0, 100.0, 0.1)
s = np.sin(0.1*np.pi*t)*np.exp(-t*0.01)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(t, s)

# Retrieve the limits of the x and y axis.
xlims = ax.get_xlim()
ylims = ax.get_ylim()

# Create two FixedLocator objects. FixedLocator objects take a sequence
# which then is translated into the tick-positions. In this case I have
# simply given the x/y limits as the sequence.
xmajorlocator = FixedLocator(xlims)
ymajorlocator = FixedLocator(ylims)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(xmajorlocator)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ymajorlocator)

# Create two LinearLocator objects for use in the minor ticks.
# LinearLocator objects take the number of ticks as an argument
# and automagically calculate the appropriate tick positions.
xminorlocator = LinearLocator(10)
yminorlocator = LinearLocator(10)

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(xminorlocator)
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(yminorlocator)

# Create two FormatStrFormatters to format the major ticks.
# I've added this simply to complete the example, you can set
# a fmt string using Python syntax to control how your ticks
# look. In this example I've formatted them as floats with
# 3 and 2 decimal places respectively.
xmajorformatter = FormatStrFormatter('%.3f')
ymajorformatter = FormatStrFormatter('%.2f')

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xmajorformatter)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ymajorformatter)

plt.show()
```

I've also included the updated graph with new tick formatting, I'll remove the old one to save space.

[image: Example plot]

Comment: Thanks! How does your solution relate to using `matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator`, `NullLocator` and `FixedLocator`?

Comment: `ax.set_xticks()` is a method of the `Axes` object, whilst `matplotlib.ticker.FixedLocator` is an object which is used with the `Axis` object (`Axes` is basically the whole graph, whilst `Axis` is just one of the (two) axis (x or y). As far as I can tell the `ax.set_xticks()` is just a convenience method that modifies the ticks, meaning a user doesn't have to worry about `matplotlib.ticker` objects. If I have some time later today then I will edit my question and add an example of using `matplotlib.ticker` objects.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added an example of how to use `Locators` and `Formatters`. Hope that helps. If you need anything else then just shout.

Comment: You should remove your original answer and just leave the edit.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think I'd prefer to leave the original answer (unless you have some reason for it changing?). It shows a simplistic method for setting ticks that will be adequate for most users. If they have a more advanced use case then they can see the edit below.